# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

I have a class like this:

```cs
public class MyStok
{
    public int STId { get; set; }
    public int SM { get; set; }
    public string CA { get; set; }
    public string Br { get; set; }
    public string BNo { get; set; }
    public decimal Vat { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I deserialize like this:

```cs
string sc = e.ExtraParams["sc"].ToString();
MyStok myobj = JSON.Deserialize<MyStok>(sc);
```

My output seems to be like this (`string sc`) on fiddler:

```
[
    {
        "STId": 2,
        "CA": "hbh",
        "Br": "jhnj",
        "SM": 20,
        "Vat": 10,
        "Price": 566,
        "BNo": "1545545"
    }
]
```

But I get the error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> [...]

What is wrong in that code?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It looks like the string contains an array with a single `MyStok` object in it. If you remove square brackets from both ends of the input, you should be able to deserialize the data as a single object:

```
MyStok myobj = JSON.Deserialize<MyStok>(sc.Substring(1, sc.Length-2));
```

You could also deserialize the array into a list of `MyStok` objects, and take the object at index zero.

```
var myobjList = JSON.Deserialize<List<MyStok>>(sc);
var myObj = myobjList[0];
```

Answer (score 28):

For array type Please try this one.

```
 List<MyStok> myDeserializedObjList = (List<MyStok>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sc, typeof(List<MyStok>));
```

Please [See here for details to deserialise Json](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C)

Comment: Thank you so much for the example, you saved my day...  I was missing the point of using a List Of.

Comment: This approach is really perfect....Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative if you have a root level array with no name and you actually want to use it for something, like adding methods

```
public class MyStoks : List<MyStok> 
{

}
```

Then you can deserialize like this

```
MyStoks myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyStoks>(jsonString);
```

Comment: This was a more elegant solution to me.  You do not have to deserialize it as a list, as the list is built into the JSON object class.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same error message.  I tried Aditi's example, and then I realized what the real issue was.  (Because I had another apiEndpoint making a similar call that worked fine.)  In this case The object in my list had not had an interface extracted from it yet.  So because I apparently missed a step, when it went to do the bind to the

```
List<OfthisModelType>
```

It failed to deserialize.

If you see this issue, check to see if that could be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("your url");
HttpResponseMessage response = await webClient.GetAsync(uri)
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var objData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CategoryModel>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: This doesn't really add any value to the question or the other answers.

Comment: this will apply only if you have HttpClient Call 
I marked as the answer is useful Cause the last line has the answer which is Deserialize it as a list of the class 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CategoryModel>>(jsonString);

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.