# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json:

```
    [
    [
        [
            {
                "origin": [
                    -15.2941064136735,
                    -0.43948581648487,
                    4.83674058264479
                ],
                "dimensions": [
                    10.4597624323399,
                    11.6903227184975,
                    9.67348116528958
                ],
                "primitive": "block"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "origin": [
                    -15.2941064136735,
                    -0.43948581648487,
                    4.83674058264479
                ],
                "dimensions": [
                    10.4597624323399,
                    11.6903227184975,
                    9.67348116528958
                ],
                "primitive": "block"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "origin": [
                    -15.2941064136735,
                    -0.43948581648487,
                    4.83674058264479
                ],
                "dimensions": [
                    10.4597624323399,
                    11.6903227184975,
                    9.67348116528958
                ],
                "primitive": "block"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

And model for this Json:

```
public class BoxConverter
    {
        [JsonProperty("origin")]
        public List<double> Origin { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dimensions")]
        public List<double> Dimensions { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("primitive")]
        public string Primitive { get; set; }
    }
```

And i try get list of objects from json which in file.

```
 string strLocal = File.ReadAllText("2.txt");
 var convertLocal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BoxConverter>>(strLocal);
```

But I have a exception :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>    because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

With this JSON work perfectly :

```
[{"attributes":{"materialProperties":{"color":"red","wireframe":false}},"dimensions":[10.4597624323399,11.6903227184975,9.67348116528958],"origin":[-15.2941064136735,-0.43948581648487,4.83674058264479],"primitive":"block"}]
```

Comment: "Origin": [   should probably be "Origin": { if I would have to take a guess (but not 100%)

Comment: it looks like there is another array around the whole thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762032/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type
this is not an answer on my question.

Comment: This looks to be a completely different JSON challenge to the duplicate link. The question that is referenced as the original does not have a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` is a `list of a list of a list of BoxConverter`.

You need to do this:

```
var convertLocal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<List<BoxConverter>>>>(strLocal)
```

Your `BoxConverter` class is fine.

If your `json` is nested an unknown amount of times (you should probably address why this is in the first place), you can do this:

```
var superHack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var currentObject = superHack;
while(currentObject is JArray)
    currentObject = currentObject[0];

var foundObject = currentObject as JObject;
var convertLocal = foundObject.ToObject<BoxConverter>();
```

Comment: But how check count of this lists inside Json. Because file can contains different Json whit different count of lists.

Comment: @VolodymyrGnatiuk See edit

Comment: var foundObject = currentObject as JObject; Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
foundObject=null;

Comment: @VolodymyrGnatiuk Then the json you're testing with is not a list of (nested lists) of objects. You should really try to standardize your json. In any case, I can't help you without seeing the json you're testing on. I tested the above on both snippets, and it works. Nevertheless, you should be able to tweak it slightly to fit your new json.

Comment: I also try the both fragments and your code not working with first fragment only. Maybe problem in reading from file?
I don't now why, but I can't get each of element in loop.
And construction currentObject as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject; return null.

Comment: Your sample working but I can get only first element .