# How I can deserialize Json into Dictionary<String,List<String>>

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I have a sample Json

```
[{"_2":["HR Data","Reformed (Master File)"]}]
```

and I am trying to deserialize it into below model

```
public class ExploreCriteria
    {
        public Dictionary<String, List<String>> Explore { get; set; }
    }
```

this is what I have tried so far

```
ExploreCriteria Explore = new ExploreCriteria();
Explore = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExploreCriteria>(JsonStr);
```

but it says

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
'DataModels.ExploreCriteria' because the type requires a JSON object
(e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

Comment: Have you tried deserializing to an array of `ExploreCriteria`, `ExploreCriteria[]`? Because your outer most thing in your JSON is an array.

Comment: Similar to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762032/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type

Comment: try `var explore = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, List<String>>>(JsonStr)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The provided JSON and your `ExploreCriteria` class do not describe the same structure.

Your JSON structure is an array that contains a key with an array value. So you can either remove the square brackets to

```
{"_2":["HR Data","Reformed (Master File)"]}
```

then your `ExploreCriteria` is fitting. Or you can change the JsonConvert call to

```
var JsonStr = "[{\"_2\":[\"HR Data\",\"Reformed(Master File)\"]}]";
ExploreCriteria Explore = new ExploreCriteria();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Dictionary<String, List<string>>>>(JsonStr);
Explore.Explore = data.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @AdilWaqar - sorry the Explore property was not fitting. I have edited the code so that it is fitting to your ´ExploreCriteria´.

Answer (score 1):

`List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> uploadedfiles =
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>>(json);`

use keyvaluepair class instead of dictionary.