# How to deserialize a json array without name to a class on C#

Tags: c#, json

I need to deserialize a json array into a C# class using Newtonsoft.Json, but I dont know how to do it.

I have already tried using

```
public  LeagueInfo[] leagueinfo { get; set; }
```

and

```
public  List<LeagueInfo> leagueinfo { get; set; }
```

What i have now is:

```
    public class League
    {
        public  LeagueInfo[] leagueinfo { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class LeagueInfo
    {
        public string queueType { get; set; }
        public string summonerName { get; set; }
        public bool hotStreak { get; set; }
        public int wins { get; set; }
        public bool veteran { get; set; }
        public int losses { get; set; }
        public string rank { get; set; }
        public string tier { get; set; }
        public bool inactive { get; set; }
        public bool freshBlood { get; set; }
        public string leagueId { get; set; }
        public string summonerId { get; set; }
        public int leaguePoints { get; set; }
    }
```

```
league = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<League>(data);
```

When i try to do that i get this error:

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'League' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
    To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
    Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

My JSON String is

```
[
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "summonerName": "R2FTW",
        "hotStreak": false,
        "wins": 76,
        "veteran": true,
        "losses": 97,
        "rank": "II",
        "tier": "BRONZE",
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "2a74bbd0-20ba-11e9-9c10-d4ae52a70a5a",
        "summonerId": "n9Sw-4lZHg5Cd2oeMxe8dj9WGv1XQS3GZEMPX1VZHgVH5w",
        "leaguePoints": 75
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
        "summonerName": "R2FTW",
        "hotStreak": false,
        "wins": 0,
        "veteran": false,
        "losses": 12,
        "rank": "IV",
        "tier": "IRON",
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "b75d4e60-2234-11e9-a815-d4ae527982aa",
        "summonerId": "n9Sw-4lZHg5Cd2oeMxe8dj9WGv1XQS3GZEMPX1VZHgVH5w",
        "leaguePoints": 0
    }
]
```

How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. \[1,2,3\]) into type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762032/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type)

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueInfo[]>(data);` should work.  Are you saying it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
League league = new League()
{
    leagueinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueInfo[]>(data)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JSON parser needs a name.
I made mine work by adding the name to the output like this:

```
var league = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'League>("{ leagueinfo: " + data + " }");
```

Of course it's a bit hacky, but if you don't receive better formatted data this could be the solution.