# Json to csharp class failed to deserialize object

Tags: c#, json

Hello i have a problem trying to deserialize a json file to and object i am using NewtonSoft

Here is my json

```
[{"attribute_id":117,"attribute_code":"custom_layout_update_file","frontend_input":"select","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"No update","value":"__no_update__"}],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Custom Layout Update","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\LayoutUpdate","source_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Source\\LayoutUpdate","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":115,"attribute_code":"quantity_and_stock_status","frontend_input":"select","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"In Stock","value":"1"},{"label":"Out of Stock","value":"0"}],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Quantity","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","backend_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\Stock","source_model":"Magento\\CatalogInventory\\Model\\Source\\Stock","default_value":"1","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":82,"attribute_code":"weight","frontend_input":"weight","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Weight","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"decimal","backend_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\Weight","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":121,"attribute_code":"weight_type","frontend_input":"boolean","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":true,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Dynamic Weight","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","default_value":"0","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":105,"attribute_code":"category_ids","frontend_input":"text","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Categories","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"static","backend_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\Category","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":99,"attribute_code":"visibility","frontend_input":"select","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"Not Visible Individually","value":"1"},{"label":"Catalog","value":"2"},{"label":"Search","value":"3"},{"label":"Catalog, Search","value":"4"}],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Visibility","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","source_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Visibility","default_value":"4","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":75,"attribute_code":"description","frontend_input":"textarea","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Description","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"text","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":94,"attribute_code":"news_from_date","frontend_input":"date","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Set Product as New from Date","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"datetime","backend_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Attribute\\Backend\\Startdate","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":76,"attribute_code":"short_description","frontend_input":"textarea","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Short Description","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"text","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":95,"attribute_code":"news_to_date","frontend_input":"date","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Set Product as New to Date","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"datetime","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\Datetime","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":114,"attribute_code":"country_of_manufacture","frontend_input":"select","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"Afghanistan","value":"AF"},{"label":"Albania","value":"AL"},{"label":"Algeria","value":"DZ"},{"label":"American Samoa","value":"AS"},{"label":"Andorra","value":"AD"},{"label":"Angola","value":"AO"},{"label":"Anguilla","value":"AI"},{"label":"Antarctica","value":"AQ"},{"label":"Antigua & Barbuda","value":"AG"},{"label":"Argentina","value":"AR"},{"label":"Armenia","value":"AM"},{"label":"Aruba","value":"AW"},{"label":"Australia","value":"AU"},{"label":"Austria","value":"AT"},{"label":"Azerbaijan","value":"AZ"},{"label":"Bahamas","value":"BS"},{"label":"Bahrain","value":"BH"},{"label":"Bangladesh","value":"BD"},{"label":"Barbados","value":"BB"},{"label":"Belarus","value":"BY"},{"label":"Belgium","value":"BE"},{"label":"Belize","value":"BZ"},{"label":"Benin","value":"BJ"},{"label":"Bermuda","value":"BM"},{"label":"Bhutan","value":"BT"},{"label":"Bolivia","value":"BO"},{"label":"Bosnia & Herzegovina","value":"BA"},{"label":"Botswana","value":"BW"},{"label":"Bouvet Island","value":"BV"},{"label":"Brazil","value":"BR"},{"label":"British Indian Ocean Territory","value":"IO"},{"label":"British Virgin Islands","value":"VG"},{"label":"Brunei","value":"BN"},{"label":"Bulgaria","value":"BG"},{"label":"Burkina Faso","value":"BF"},{"label":"Burundi","value":"BI"},{"label":"Cambodia","value":"KH"},{"label":"Cameroon","value":"CM"},{"label":"Canada","value":"CA"},{"label":"Cape Verde","value":"CV"},{"label":"Caribbean Netherlands","value":"BQ"},{"label":"Cayman Islands","value":"KY"},{"label":"Central African Republic","value":"CF"},{"label":"Chad","value":"TD"},{"label":"Chile","value":"CL"},{"label":"China","value":"CN"},{"label":"Christmas Island","value":"CX"},{"label":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","value":"CC"},{"label":"Colombia","value":"CO"},{"label":"Comoros","value":"KM"},{"label":"Congo - Brazzaville","value":"CG"},{"label":"Congo - Kinshasa","value":"CD"},{"label":"Cook Islands","value":"CK"},{"label":"Costa Rica","value":"CR"},{"label":"Croatia","value":"HR"},{"label":"Cuba","value":"CU"},{"label":"Cura\u00e7ao","value":"CW"},{"label":"Cyprus","value":"CY"},{"label":"Czechia","value":"CZ"},{"label":"C\u00f4te d\u2019Ivoire","value":"CI"},{"label":"Denmark","value":"DK"},{"label":"Djibouti","value":"DJ"},{"label":"Dominica","value":"DM"},{"label":"Dominican Republic","value":"DO"},{"label":"Ecuador","value":"EC"},{"label":"Egypt","value":"EG"},{"label":"El Salvador","value":"SV"},{"label":"Equatorial Guinea","value":"GQ"},{"label":"Eritrea","value":"ER"},{"label":"Estonia","value":"EE"},{"label":"Eswatini","value":"SZ"},{"label":"Ethiopia","value":"ET"},{"label":"Falkland Islands","value":"FK"},{"label":"Faroe Islands","value":"FO"},{"label":"Fiji","value":"FJ"},{"label":"Finland","value":"FI"},{"label":"France","value":"FR"},{"label":"French Guiana","value":"GF"},{"label":"French Polynesia","value":"PF"},{"label":"French Southern Territories","value":"TF"},{"label":"Gabon","value":"GA"},{"label":"Gambia","value":"GM"},{"label":"Georgia","value":"GE"},{"label":"Germany","value":"DE"},{"label":"Ghana","value":"GH"},{"label":"Gibraltar","value":"GI"},{"label":"Greece","value":"GR"},{"label":"Greenland","value":"GL"},{"label":"Grenada","value":"GD"},{"label":"Guadeloupe","value":"GP"},{"label":"Guam","value":"GU"},{"label":"Guatemala","value":"GT"},{"label":"Guernsey","value":"GG"},{"label":"Guinea","value":"GN"},{"label":"Guinea-Bissau","value":"GW"},{"label":"Guyana","value":"GY"},{"label":"Haiti","value":"HT"},{"label":"Heard & McDonald Islands","value":"HM"},{"label":"Honduras","value":"HN"},{"label":"Hong Kong SAR China","value":"HK"},{"label":"Hungary","value":"HU"},{"label":"Iceland","value":"IS"},{"label":"India","value":"IN"},{"label":"Indonesia","value":"ID"},{"label":"Iran","value":"IR"},{"label":"Iraq","value":"IQ"},{"label":"Ireland","value":"IE"},{"label":"Isle of Man","value":"IM"},{"label":"Israel","value":"IL"},{"label":"Italy","value":"IT"},{"label":"Jamaica","value":"JM"},{"label":"Japan","value":"JP"},{"label":"Jersey","value":"JE"},{"label":"Jordan","value":"JO"},{"label":"Kazakhstan","value":"KZ"},{"label":"Kenya","value":"KE"},{"label":"Kiribati","value":"KI"},{"label":"Kosovo","value":"XK"},{"label":"Kuwait","value":"KW"},{"label":"Kyrgyzstan","value":"KG"},{"label":"Laos","value":"LA"},{"label":"Latvia","value":"LV"},{"label":"Lebanon","value":"LB"},{"label":"Lesotho","value":"LS"},{"label":"Liberia","value":"LR"},{"label":"Libya","value":"LY"},{"label":"Liechtenstein","value":"LI"},{"label":"Lithuania","value":"LT"},{"label":"Luxembourg","value":"LU"},{"label":"Macao SAR China","value":"MO"},{"label":"Madagascar","value":"MG"},{"label":"Malawi","value":"MW"},{"label":"Malaysia","value":"MY"},{"label":"Maldives","value":"MV"},{"label":"Mali","value":"ML"},{"label":"Malta","value":"MT"},{"label":"Marshall Islands","value":"MH"},{"label":"Martinique","value":"MQ"},{"label":"Mauritania","value":"MR"},{"label":"Mauritius","value":"MU"},{"label":"Mayotte","value":"YT"},{"label":"Mexico","value":"MX"},{"label":"Micronesia","value":"FM"},{"label":"Moldova","value":"MD"},{"label":"Monaco","value":"MC"},{"label":"Mongolia","value":"MN"},{"label":"Montenegro","value":"ME"},{"label":"Montserrat","value":"MS"},{"label":"Morocco","value":"MA"},{"label":"Mozambique","value":"MZ"},{"label":"Myanmar (Burma)","value":"MM"},{"label":"Namibia","value":"NA"},{"label":"Nauru","value":"NR"},{"label":"Nepal","value":"NP"},{"label":"Netherlands","value":"NL"},{"label":"New Caledonia","value":"NC"},{"label":"New Zealand","value":"NZ"},{"label":"Nicaragua","value":"NI"},{"label":"Niger","value":"NE"},{"label":"Nigeria","value":"NG"},{"label":"Niue","value":"NU"},{"label":"Norfolk Island","value":"NF"},{"label":"North Korea","value":"KP"},{"label":"North Macedonia","value":"MK"},{"label":"Northern Mariana Islands","value":"MP"},{"label":"Norway","value":"NO"},{"label":"Oman","value":"OM"},{"label":"Pakistan","value":"PK"},{"label":"Palau","value":"PW"},{"label":"Palestinian Territories","value":"PS"},{"label":"Panama","value":"PA"},{"label":"Papua New Guinea","value":"PG"},{"label":"Paraguay","value":"PY"},{"label":"Peru","value":"PE"},{"label":"Philippines","value":"PH"},{"label":"Pitcairn Islands","value":"PN"},{"label":"Poland","value":"PL"},{"label":"Portugal","value":"PT"},{"label":"Qatar","value":"QA"},{"label":"Romania","value":"RO"},{"label":"Russia","value":"RU"},{"label":"Rwanda","value":"RW"},{"label":"R\u00e9union","value":"RE"},{"label":"Samoa","value":"WS"},{"label":"San Marino","value":"SM"},{"label":"Saudi Arabia","value":"SA"},{"label":"Senegal","value":"SN"},{"label":"Serbia","value":"RS"},{"label":"Seychelles","value":"SC"},{"label":"Sierra Leone","value":"SL"},{"label":"Singapore","value":"SG"},{"label":"Sint Maarten","value":"SX"},{"label":"Slovakia","value":"SK"},{"label":"Slovenia","value":"SI"},{"label":"Solomon Islands","value":"SB"},{"label":"Somalia","value":"SO"},{"label":"South Africa","value":"ZA"},{"label":"South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands","value":"GS"},{"label":"South Korea","value":"KR"},{"label":"Spain","value":"ES"},{"label":"Sri Lanka","value":"LK"},{"label":"St. Barth\u00e9lemy","value":"BL"},{"label":"St. Helena","value":"SH"},{"label":"St. Kitts & Nevis","value":"KN"},{"label":"St. Lucia","value":"LC"},{"label":"St. Martin","value":"MF"},{"label":"St. Pierre & Miquelon","value":"PM"},{"label":"St. Vincent & Grenadines","value":"VC"},{"label":"Sudan","value":"SD"},{"label":"Suriname","value":"SR"},{"label":"Svalbard & Jan Mayen","value":"SJ"},{"label":"Sweden","value":"SE"},{"label":"Switzerland","value":"CH"},{"label":"Syria","value":"SY"},{"label":"S\u00e3o Tom\u00e9 & Pr\u00edncipe","value":"ST"},{"label":"Taiwan, Province of China","value":"TW"},{"label":"Tajikistan","value":"TJ"},{"label":"Tanzania","value":"TZ"},{"label":"Thailand","value":"TH"},{"label":"Timor-Leste","value":"TL"},{"label":"Togo","value":"TG"},{"label":"Tokelau","value":"TK"},{"label":"Tonga","value":"TO"},{"label":"Trinidad & Tobago","value":"TT"},{"label":"Tunisia","value":"TN"},{"label":"Turkey","value":"TR"},{"label":"Turkmenistan","value":"TM"},{"label":"Turks & Caicos Islands","value":"TC"},{"label":"Tuvalu","value":"TV"},{"label":"U.S. Outlying Islands","value":"UM"},{"label":"U.S. Virgin Islands","value":"VI"},{"label":"Uganda","value":"UG"},{"label":"Ukraine","value":"UA"},{"label":"United Arab Emirates","value":"AE"},{"label":"United Kingdom","value":"GB"},{"label":"United States","value":"US","is_default":true},{"label":"Uruguay","value":"UY"},{"label":"Uzbekistan","value":"UZ"},{"label":"Vanuatu","value":"VU"},{"label":"Vatican City","value":"VA"},{"label":"Venezuela","value":"VE"},{"label":"Vietnam","value":"VN"},{"label":"Wallis & Futuna","value":"WF"},{"label":"Western Sahara","value":"EH"},{"label":"Yemen","value":"YE"},{"label":"Zambia","value":"ZM"},{"label":"Zimbabwe","value":"ZW"},{"label":"\u00c5land Islands","value":"AX"}],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Country of Manufacture","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","source_model":"Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Source\\Countryofmanufacture","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":130,"attribute_code":"links_purchased_separately","frontend_input":null,"entity_type_id":"4","is_required":true,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Links can be purchased separately","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":131,"attribute_code":"samples_title","frontend_input":null,"entity_type_id":"4","is_required":true,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Samples title","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":132,"attribute_code":"links_title","frontend_input":null,"entity_type_id":"4","is_required":true,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"default_frontend_label":"Links title","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":133,"attribute_code":"links_exist","frontend_input":null,"entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[],"is_user_defined":false,"frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":136,"attribute_code":"activity","frontend_input":"multiselect","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"Hike","value":"4"},{"label":"Outdoor","value":"5"},{"label":"Running","value":"6"},{"label":"Warmup","value":"7"},{"label":"Yoga","value":"8"},{"label":"Recreation","value":"9"},{"label":"Lounge","value":"10"},{"label":"Gym","value":"11"},{"label":"Climbing","value":"12"},{"label":"Crosstraining","value":"13"},{"label":"Post-workout","value":"14"},{"label":"Cycling","value":"15"},{"label":"Athletic","value":"16"},{"label":"Sports","value":"17"},{"label":"Hiking","value":"18"},{"label":"Overnight","value":"19"},{"label":"School","value":"20"},{"label":"Trail","value":"21"},{"label":"Travel","value":"22"},{"label":"Urban","value":"23"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Activity","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":151,"attribute_code":"style_general","frontend_input":"multiselect","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"Insulated","value":"116"},{"label":"Jacket","value":"117"},{"label":"Vest","value":"118"},{"label":"Lightweight","value":"119"},{"label":"Hooded","value":"120"},{"label":"Heavy Duty","value":"121"},{"label":"Rain Coat","value":"122"},{"label":"Hard Shell","value":"123"},{"label":"Soft Shell","value":"124"},{"label":"Windbreaker","value":"125"},{"label":"&frac12; zip","value":"126"},{"label":"&frac14; zip","value":"127"},{"label":"Full Zip","value":"128"},{"label":"Reversible","value":"129"},{"label":"Bra","value":"130"},{"label":"Hoodie","value":"131"},{"label":"Sweatshirt","value":"132"},{"label":"Polo","value":"133"},{"label":"Tank","value":"134"},{"label":"Tee","value":"135"},{"label":"Pullover","value":"136"},{"label":"Hoodie","value":"137"},{"label":"Cardigan","value":"138"},{"label":"Henley","value":"139"},{"label":"Tunic","value":"140"},{"label":"Camisole","value":"141"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Style General","frontend_labels":[{"store_id":1,"label":"Style"}],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":138,"attribute_code":"material","frontend_input":"multiselect","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"Burlap","value":"31"},{"label":"Cocona&reg; performance fabric","value":"142"},{"label":"Canvas","value":"32"},{"label":"Wool","value":"143"},{"label":"Cotton","value":"33"},{"label":"Fleece","value":"144"},{"label":"Faux Leather","value":"34"},{"label":"Hemp","value":"145"},{"label":"Jersey","value":"146"},{"label":"Leather","value":"35"},{"label":"LumaTech&trade;","value":"147"},{"label":"Mesh","value":"36"},{"label":"Lycra&reg;","value":"148"},{"label":"Nylon","value":"37"},{"label":"Microfiber","value":"149"},{"label":"Polyester","value":"38"},{"label":"Rayon","value":"39"},{"label":"Spandex","value":"150"},{"label":"HeatTec&reg;","value":"151"},{"label":"Ripstop","value":"40"},{"label":"EverCool&trade;","value":"152"},{"label":"Suede","value":"41"},{"label":"Foam","value":"42"},{"label":"Organic Cotton","value":"153"},{"label":"Metal","value":"43"},{"label":"TENCEL","value":"154"},{"label":"CoolTech&trade;","value":"155"},{"label":"Plastic","value":"44"},{"label":"Khaki","value":"156"},{"label":"Rubber","value":"45"},{"label":"Linen","value":"157"},{"label":"Synthetic","value":"46"},{"label":"Stainless Steel","value":"47"},{"label":"Wool","value":"158"},{"label":"Silicone","value":"48"},{"label":"Terry","value":"159"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Material","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":152,"attribute_code":"sleeve","frontend_input":"multiselect","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"Sleeve","value":"160"},{"label":"Long-Sleeve","value":"161"},{"label":"Short-Sleeve","value":"162"},{"label":"Sleeveless","value":"163"},{"label":"Tank","value":"164"},{"label":"Strap","value":"165"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Sleeve","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":143,"attribute_code":"size","frontend_input":"select","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"55 cm","value":"91"},{"label":"XS","value":"166"},{"label":"65 cm","value":"92"},{"label":"S","value":"167"},{"label":"75 cm","value":"93"},{"label":"M","value":"168"},{"label":"6 foot","value":"94"},{"label":"L","value":"169"},{"label":"8 foot","value":"95"},{"label":"XL","value":"170"},{"label":"10 foot","value":"96"},{"label":"28","value":"171"},{"label":"29","value":"172"},{"label":"30","value":"173"},{"label":"31","value":"174"},{"label":"32","value":"175"},{"label":"33","value":"176"},{"label":"34","value":"177"},{"label":"36","value":"178"},{"label":"38","value":"179"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Size","frontend_labels":[{"store_id":1,"label":"Size"}],"backend_type":"int","default_value":"91","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":153,"attribute_code":"collar","frontend_input":"multiselect","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"N\/A","value":"180"},{"label":"? zip","value":"181"},{"label":"Boat Neck","value":"182"},{"label":"Crew","value":"183"},{"label":"Full zip","value":"184"},{"label":"V-neck","value":"185"},{"label":"Ballet","value":"186"},{"label":"Scoop","value":"187"},{"label":"High Collar","value":"188"},{"label":"Stand Collar","value":"189"},{"label":"Roll Neck","value":"190"},{"label":"Square Neck","value":"191"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Collar","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":154,"attribute_code":"pattern","frontend_input":"multiselect","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"Color-Blocked","value":"192"},{"label":"Checked","value":"193"},{"label":"Color-Blocked","value":"194"},{"label":"Graphic Print","value":"195"},{"label":"Solid","value":"196"},{"label":"Solid-Highlight","value":"197"},{"label":"Striped","value":"198"},{"label":"Camo","value":"199"},{"label":"Geometric","value":"200"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Pattern","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":155,"attribute_code":"climate","frontend_input":"multiselect","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"All-Weather","value":"201"},{"label":"Cold","value":"202"},{"label":"Cool","value":"203"},{"label":"Indoor","value":"204"},{"label":"Mild","value":"205"},{"label":"Rainy","value":"206"},{"label":"Spring","value":"207"},{"label":"Warm","value":"208"},{"label":"Windy","value":"209"},{"label":"Wintry","value":"210"},{"label":"Hot","value":"211"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Climate","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"varchar","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":93,"attribute_code":"color","frontend_input":"select","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":" ","value":""},{"label":"Black","value":"49"},{"label":"Blue","value":"50"},{"label":"Brown","value":"51"},{"label":"Gray","value":"52"},{"label":"Green","value":"53"},{"label":"Lavender","value":"54"},{"label":"Multi","value":"55"},{"label":"Orange","value":"56"},{"label":"Purple","value":"57"},{"label":"Red","value":"58"},{"label":"White","value":"59"},{"label":"Yellow","value":"60"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Color","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","backend_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\DefaultBackend","default_value":"49","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":144,"attribute_code":"eco_collection","frontend_input":"boolean","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"Yes","value":"1"},{"label":"No","value":"0"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Eco Collection","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","source_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Boolean","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":145,"attribute_code":"performance_fabric","frontend_input":"boolean","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"Yes","value":"1"},{"label":"No","value":"0"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Performance Fabric","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","source_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Boolean","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":146,"attribute_code":"erin_recommends","frontend_input":"boolean","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"Yes","value":"1"},{"label":"No","value":"0"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Erin Recommends","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","source_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Boolean","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":147,"attribute_code":"new","frontend_input":"boolean","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"Yes","value":"1"},{"label":"No","value":"0"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"New","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","source_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Boolean","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]},{"attribute_id":148,"attribute_code":"sale","frontend_input":"boolean","entity_type_id":"4","is_required":false,"options":[{"label":"Yes","value":"1"},{"label":"No","value":"0"}],"is_user_defined":true,"default_frontend_label":"Sale","frontend_labels":[],"backend_type":"int","source_model":"Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Boolean","default_value":"","is_unique":"0","validation_rules":[]}]
```

And here are my json class objects

```
public class Option
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class FrontendLabel
{
    public string store_id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class MyArray
{
    public string attribute_id { get; set; }
    public string attribute_code { get; set; }
    public string frontend_input { get; set; }
    public string entity_type_id { get; set; }
    public bool is_required { get; set; }
    public List<Option> options { get; set; }
    public bool is_user_defined { get; set; }
    public List<FrontendLabel> frontend_labels { get; set; }
    public string backend_type { get; set; }
    public string is_unique { get; set; }
    public List<object> validation_rules { get; set; }
    public string default_frontend_label { get; set; }
    public string backend_model { get; set; }
    public string default_value { get; set; }
    public string source_model { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

But i am getting this error

**{"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Magento.Products.AttributeId.Root' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."}**

Plus here is how i am getting the json

```
public Root GetAttributeSets(string attributeCode)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = CreateRequestAuthorized("/rest/default/V1/products/attribute-sets/" + attributeCode + "/attributes", Method.GET);
            var response = Client.Execute(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Error getting list categories");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. \[1,2,3\]) into type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762032/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type)

Comment: The first char of the json is a `[`, that indicate an Array. You should try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(response.Content)` like the error message says : "_change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface_"

Comment: And 35K char is not Minimal, [mre]. If the issue was not the first char, then copy pasting and formating would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the JavaScript object you have isn't an object, it's an array.  So instead of an instance of `Root` what you have is an instance of `List<MyArray>`:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyArray>>(response.Content);
```

To have an instance of `Root` the JavaScript object would need to be something like:

```
{"MyArray": [/* your current JSON */]}
```